# signalr group is not created after using add

Tags: signalr

I have this code in which I add two signalR connectID's to a group,

```
Groups.Add(student.connID, "groupA");
Groups.Add(less.connID, "groupA");
```

After that I try to send messgae to this group with the following code -

```
Clients.Group("groupA").goLesson();
```

but code nver reach the goLesson client function.

I also tried to use async function with

```
await Groups.Add(student.connID, "groupA");
await Groups.Add(less.connID, "groupA");
```

still seems like group "groupA" is not created.

any idea why ?

Comment: How do you test whether a group is created ?

Comment: I tried calling Clients.Group("myGroup").clientFunction

Comment: try calling the client using Clients.ALL.goLesson(); to see if the client can be connected at all

Comment: That's what I did, and it did wotk with Clients.All.
Anyway after using the joinGroup function it is working just fine, thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the following function that adds user to a group -

```
    **private void joinGroup(string groupName, string userID){
        this.Groups.Add(userID, groupName);
    }**
```